# Operator overloading methods added during migration to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have migrated my code to `Swift 3.0`. During migration, below code is added to some of the files. It was not there previously with `swift 2.2`.

**Codes added :**

```
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

fileprivate func > <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l > r
  default:
    return rhs < lhs
  }
}
```

What is the meaning of this code and why is it added on its own?

Comment: Optional comparison is not supported by default in Swift 3.0. If you have done any optional comparison in those files, then Swift 3 migrator adds this function.